# SQL Scaling: should I try to minimize queries when having multiple OR column conditions?

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, scalability

My DB schema is

```
INTEGER id
TIME_STAMP last_updated   // indexed
VARCHAR url               // indexed

// Place attributes
VARCHAR name              // indexed
VARCHAR address           // indexed
VARCHAR phone             // indexed

INTEGER score
```

Out of name, address, and phone fields, one of them must be non-empty, and the other two empty.

Valid examples:

```
{name="Pizza Hut", address=null, phone=null, score=40}
```

Invalid examples:

```
{name="Pizza Hut", address="some address", phone=null, score=40}
```

I'm trying to write this function.

```
// return a map/dictionary of String keys and Integer scores of latest data in DB that matches given url, and is not older than last_updated.
// example: {name=40, address=50, phone=66}
public Map getPlaceAnalysis(String name_, String address_, String phone_, String url, DateTime last_updated_);
```

Scaling assumptions:

- This function will be getting called very frequently.
- DB has millions of rows
- name, phone, address may not be my only fields. I may have 20+ attributes about a place.

There are two approaches:

1. 3 (or the number of attributes about a Place stored in the DB) queries:

   ```
   SELECT score FROM db_name WHERE name=name_ AND url = url_ AND last_updated > last_updated_
   SELECT score FROM db_name WHERE phone=phone_ AND url = url_ AND last_updated > last_updated_
   SELECT score FROM db_name WHERE address=address_ AND url = url_ AND last_updated > last_updated_
   ```

   After each query, I can select the latest row and write the score into my map/dictionary to be returned for the appropriate key.
2. 1 query:

   ```
   SELECT name, phone, address, score FROM db_name WHERE (name=name_ OR phone=phone_ OR address=address_ ) AND url = url_ AND last_updated > last_updated_
   ```

   I then loop through the query results and figure out the most updated row for name, phone, and address, and return the appropriate map/dictionary.

Does it matter which approach I take? I'm guessing the second one is better, but I have very little experience with databases. Sorry if any explanation is unclear. I'd imagine this is a pretty common problem but couldn't figure out how to search for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When running a query to a remote database there is a considerable amount of time spent in establishing the connection and stuff like that, that are more related to the communication with the database and not so much with the query itself. From this point of view you want to minimize the number of queries you issue to the database.

As explained in MYSQL reference manual for [Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), it seems that it would be to your benefit to create a composite index on the three fields you are using in your query. This index would also be used when you search for `name` only, `name` and `address` and all the three fields together (see what it says about leftmost prefixes) so pay attention to the order you are going to declare the index.

The idea of the hash of the three fields seems also interesting, if it can be used in your case.

Finally you should read about [Understanding the Query Execution Plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execution-plan-information.html) and/or have a database administrator to help you with that.

The key thing to understand when talking about query performance is to design a repeatable test case (i.e. with the same set of data, a repeatable database load etc) and then try your different approaches. And always watch out for differences between the environment you test and your production environment.

I hope that helps.